# Is there a python xarray function, like interp, to lookup the closest coordinate value that matches a variable value?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am looking for a way to return the interpolated coordinate value of a variable at a query variable value. I think it is the opposite use to a normal interpolation/table-look up.

For example, here is a simple, normal interpolation,
From this very good [tutorial](https://earth-env-data-science.github.io/lectures/xarray/xarray-part2.html):

```
x_data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
f = xr.DataArray(x_data**2, dims=['x'], coords={'x': x_data})
f.plot(marker='o')
```

Which produces this plot:
[image: simple plot of data]

So a standard lookup (e.g. `f.interp(x=4.5)`) would look for the value of the variable at some coordinate value of `x`. But I want to look for the value of the `x` where the variable is equal to some value. For example in the above plot, what is the value of `x` where the variable equals `20`.

I am ultimately trying to do this for a 3D field of temperature (longitude x latitude x depth). So, how do I find the value of depth, where the temperature field is closest to a value that I specify.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a simple method for solving this using `scipy.interpolate` which works, though is relatively slow to compute.

```
from scipy import interpolate

ii = interpolate.interp1d(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])**2,np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
ii(20)
```

Which returns `array(4.44444444)`.

I think this is *an answer*, which might help someone, but not the ideal answer. Ideally this could be done in a pythonic manner, perhaps using the `xarray` module.

To extend this to 3D, I had to loop it within 2 for-loops, like this:

```
def calc_depthToTempROMS(tempfield,depthfield,queryfield,xxlims,eelims):
    ## the two input fields are the tempfield (equivalent to the coordinates) and the depthfield (equivalent to the function to be interpolated). 
    ## queryfield is the values of temperature to interpolate for depth.
    ## xxlims and eelims are the for-loop bounds, which are model specific
    for xx in xxlims:
        for ee in eelims:
            ii = interpolate.interp1d(tempfield.isel(xi_rho=xx,eta_rho=ee),depthfield.isel(xi_rho=xx,eta_rho=ee)) # make the interpolator
            depthTC[dict(eta_rho=ee,xi_rho=xx)] = ii(queryfield.isel(xi_rho=xx,eta_rho=ee)) # interpolate for each location
        if xx.values in np.round(np.linspace(0,len(xxlims.values),10)):
            print(xx.values) # print every 10th index to monitor progress
    return depthTC


depthTC = (truth.tempTC.mean(dim='ocean_time')*np.nan).load() # initialise an empty matrix
tempfield = truth.temp.mean(dim='ocean_time').load() # coordinates
depthfield = truth.z_rho0.load() # function to interpolate
queryfield = truth.tempTC.mean(dim='ocean_time').load() # target coordinate
xxlims = truth.xi_rho.load()
eelims = truth.eta_rho.load()

depthTC = calc_depthToTempROMS(tempfield,depthfield,queryfield,xxlims,eelims)
```

Someone else using `xarray` for processing earth science model data may find the above code useful.

I will leave this unaccepted for now - hopefully someone can come up with a better, `xarray`-based method for achieving this.